# Why use 行き and not 行きたい?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I'm currently learning the Desire Form of the verbs and I'd like to know why in this phrase, it's used 行き and not 行きたい.

> 私はショッピングモールに**行き**、自分のために服を買いたい

The たい form should be added only at the last verb? Like in this case that it goes to the 買います verb. Is that a rule? Does it work for other verb conjugations such as Past and/or Conditional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 行き in the first part of the sentence is the 連用形 (れんようけい, also known as the masu-stem) and it's often used in writing the same way that the て form is used to act to connect two related clauses into one sentence. So it has no implication of desire, it's the same as if it said 行って, but is typically used this way in writing.

Comment: So 行って is the same as 行き? Therefore, 行き would only be used in letters or something, is that right? In daily conversations it's better to use 行って. Did I get it right this time?

Comment: In this case they would be interchangeable in their meaning. And yes, using 連用形 in writing would feel a bit stiffer and you wouldn't use it in conversation.