# 青春とは噓であり、悪である　‐　あり　vs　ある？

Tags: meaning, sentence

So this is a line from the anime Oregairu. From what I know, I would say ある and あり mean the same thing. However, I could be wrong so is there any special reason why 'ari' was used first and 'aru' was used second in this sentence?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9771/9831

Answer (score 2):

青春とは噓であり、悪である is a single sentence.

The first あり is an example of using the masu-stem as a connector similar to the te-form. See also [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/54134/17571) and [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/41142/17571).